# Why are distributions only defined on maps with compact support?

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Why do we restrict ourselves to maps of compact support, what’s wrong with merely smooth functions or some more general space.

Comment: What specifically are you discussing? Mathematicians deal with all of the categories you've mentioned. Compact sets tend to be viewed as "small" sets, so sets with compact supports are functions that are non-zero on a "small" set. This makes analyzing them a bit more reasonable than more general functions.

Comment: People do study other domains for distributions; see, for example, the Schwarz class. But the bigger you make the domain of your distributions, the fewer distributions you can define. (For example the distributions on the Schwarz class, which are called tempered distributions, exclude $f \mapsto \int_0^\infty e^x f(x) dx$.)

Answer (score 1):

Re: "Why do we restrict ourselves to maps of compact support", we don't. The space of smooth functions $\mathscr{E}(\Omega)$ is perfectly fine as a space of test functions. It has a natural Frechet space topology which is the locally convex topology define by the collection of seminorms
$$
f\longmapsto\ \sup_{x\in K} \max_{|\alpha|\le n} |\partial^{\alpha}f(x)|
$$
where $K$ ranges over compact subsets of $\Omega$ and $n$ ranges over nonnegative integers.
The topological dual $\mathscr{E}'(\Omega)$ is the space of compactly supported distributions which can be seen as a subset of $\mathscr{D}'(\Omega)$.

Elementary introductions to the theory of distributions don't mention these spaces much but you can find more information in more substantial treatments like the book by Schwartz or the one by Horváth.

Comment: I don't think the OP cares about the topological considerations :) If $T$ is compactly supported then we can consider $C^\infty$, if it is also the $k$-th derivative of a continuous function then we can consider $C^k$, ie. we can enlarge the space depending on the distribution we are looking at

Comment: @reuns: I don't presume to know what the OP cares about or not. My point is one could imagine an introduction to distributions which only talks about $\mathscr{E},\mathscr{E}'$ and does not mention $\mathscr{D},\mathscr{D}'$ at all. Sure, such a presentation would develop a rather limited theory, but it is possible to do so in a self-contained manner. But for that one needs to define $\mathscr{E}'$ which requires at least some discussion of topology on $\mathscr{E}$.